# How to find out the TeamID of installed apps in macOS High Sierra/Mojave

Tags: macos, high-sierra, mojave

Can someone tell me, how can I get the TeamID & bundleID of all installed apps in macOS.

I know how to get the bundleID of an app, I want both TeamID and bundleID of all the installed app.

Is there any shell script/command which can be used for this?

Comment: See [this site](https://technology.siprep.org/getting-the-team-id-of-kernel-extensions-in-macos-10-13-and-higher/) and [this one](http://osxdaily.com/2016/03/14/verify-code-sign-apps-mac-os-x/) for some background. Please edit your question, or create a comment, which tells us what you’ve tried already, but doesn’t work. If you’re trying to find out this info to create profiles for managed Macs to handle new security restrictions when installing kernel extensions, there are numerous discussions on JAMF and Meraki user and support fora.

Comment: I am trying the create Profile for whitelisting the apps. The Profile needs two parameters(AppId & BundleId) of app for whitelisting apps. For now, I am looking into whitelisting the default apps which comes preinstalled with mac, hence I was looking for article/script which can point out to get the app_ids from mac.

Comment: @IconDaemon I looked at the first article which you pointed, its says to install KEXTs, but not sure which KEXT I have to install to get the AppID of all installed apps in mac.

Comment: @IconDaemon why don't you post this as an answer? It seems the first page you've linked to contains a valid approach — running e.g.  `codesign -dv --verbose=4 /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app/ 2>&1 | grep TeamIdentifier ` returns Google's TeamIdentifier `EQHXZ8M8AV`

Comment: I'm not posting this as an answer because I am not sure if this actually works, and was the result of a few minutes of Googling. If Kalpesh finds that he can work from the links I provided for a solution, I expect that he will comment to the affirmative at which point I will move it into an answer.

Comment: @IconDaemon You can post it as answer. I got hint to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

See [this site](https://technology.siprep.org/getting-the-team-id-of-kernel-extensions-in-macos-10-13-and-higher/) and [this one](http://osxdaily.com/2016/03/14/verify-code-sign-apps-mac-os-x/) for some background.

If you’re trying to find out this info to create profiles for managed Macs to handle new security restrictions when installing kernel extensions, there are numerous discussions on JAMF and Meraki user and support fora.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following command in `Terminal.app`:

```
codesign -dv /Path/To/Some.app 2>&1 | grep TeamIdentifier
```